# Azure Devops IIS Web App Deploy replace variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure Devops to release an appliction using the IIS Web App Deploy task. It has an option to to do XML Variable Substituion but only in appSettngs, applicationSettings and connectionStrings sections of any config file and parameters.xml file.

However I am trying to deploy a Sitecore CMS solution which contains it's own  section in config file which the default substitution functionality therefore does not replace.

Is there a way to get variable subsitution working like this?

Comment: Did you tried below extension task, How did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a parameters.xml file to set up a replacement in each of the xml files and then using the Replace tokens marketplace step to replace the default values when it does a deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I use magic-chunks config transformations https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks
trying installing that plugin on azure devops, very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Magic Chunks Task would be the best option.

You can go to your pipeline editing page, and follow the steps shown in below pic to search and install magic chunks to your organization.
[image]

After it is installed to organization, You need to add it before IIS Web App Deploy task. Then locate the path of config file by click the 3 dots. Shown as below. Click [Here](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks) for detailed usage

[image: enter code here]